# What does `action errdisable` do differently when issuing `power inline police`?

Tags: cisco, switch, power-over-ethernet

While learning for my CCNA exam, I was looking over Cisco's [PoE guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3650/software/release/3se/consolidated_guide/configuration_guide/b_consolidated_3650_3se_cg/b_consolidated_3650_3se_cg_chapter_01011.html). It explains how to configure PoE so that a port changes its behavior when a device draws too much power:

> `power inline police`: Shuts down the PoE port, turns off power to it, and puts it in the error-disabled state.

> `power inline police action errdisable`: Turns off power to the port if the real-time power consumption exceeds the maximum power allocation on the port.

It says below:

> If you do not enter the `action log` keywords, the default action shuts down the port and puts the port in the error-disabled state.

So what is the difference between `power inline police` and `power inline police action errdisable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Power inline police command is equivalent to the #power inline police action errdisable. Another option is the #power inline police action log. First, two would put the port into an error disable state, 3rd one would only notify, and generate a log entry. You can always confirm by issuing command:

```
Switch# show power inline police
Available:623(w)  Used:6(w)  Remaining:617(w)
Interface Admin  Oper       Admin       Oper         Cutoff Oper
          State  State      Police      Police       Power  Power
--------- ------ ---------- ----------  ----------   ------ -----
Gi2/1     auto   off        none        n/a          n/a    0.0
Gi2/2     auto   on         none        n/a          n/a    16.7
Gi2/3     auto   off        errdisable  n/a          0.0    0.0
Gi2/4     auto   on         errdisable  ok           16.6   11.4
Gi2/5     auto   on         log         ok           16.6   11.2
Gi2/6     auto   on         errdisable  overdrawn    0.0    0.0
```